# Center items in a row if they don't fit all space

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an array of images and I have to draw them in a canvas as a grid, with given columns. I do it with the following functions, that receives the number of columns the grid will have, the index of the element, the image or sprite, the position (it will be the same initial position for every element), and a padding between the elements (will be the same for all).

```
  getImagePosition({ columns, i, sprite, position, padding }) {
    const tempX = (i % columns);
    const tempY = (i - tempX) / columns;
    const x = ((padding.left + sprite.width) * tempX) + position.x;
    const y = ((padding.top + sprite.height) * (tempY + 1)) + position.y;
    return { x, y };
  }
```

This draws me the grid but in case that there are not enough elements to fit a row, they should be positioned towards the center, like in this fiddle (it's just a quick demo with flexbox to show what's my current aligmnent and the desired result): https://jsfiddle.net/j4o3qxk0/

The images are all the same one, so it's equal width and padding for all elements, and I need to calculate with that function the X coordinate of each element's starting point (top-left corner), but I haven't figured it out how to do it. Could you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const finalRowEmptyCols = rows * cols - imgs.length;
const finalRowEndPadding = finalRowEmptyCols * (imgWidth + padding) / 2;
```

Then `finalRowEndPadding` represents the amount of extra padding you add to the final row.  This implies that in your function you will need the total number of images being drawn, first so you can calculate the amount of extra padding, and second so you know when you're drawing the final row so you can add in the extra padding.

Here is a working snippet in case it helps explain what I mean:

```js
function generateTestImages(count, width, height) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const testImages = [];
  for (let itr = 0; itr < count; ++itr) {
    context.fillStyle = '#' + Math.ceil((Math.random() * Math.pow(255, 3))).toString(16);
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    testImages.push(context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height));
  }
  return testImages;
}

const padding = 10;
const imgWidth = 110;
const imgHeight = 110;
const imgs = generateTestImages(33, imgWidth, imgHeight);

const canvasWidth = 700;
let minimumRowWidth = padding * 2 + imgWidth;
let cols = 1;
while (minimumRowWidth + imgWidth + padding <= canvasWidth) {
  minimumRowWidth += imgWidth + padding;
  ++cols;
}
const rowEndPadding = (canvasWidth - minimumRowWidth) / 2;
const rows = Math.ceil(imgs.length / cols);
const canvasHeight = rows * (imgHeight + padding) + padding;
const finalRowEmptyCols = rows * cols - imgs.length;
const finalRowEndPadding = finalRowEmptyCols * (imgWidth + padding) / 2;

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = canvasWidth;
canvas.height = canvasHeight;
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);  
let xx = rowEndPadding + padding;
let yy = padding;
let col = 0;
let row = 0;
imgs.forEach(img => {
  context.putImageData(img, xx, yy);
  xx += imgWidth + padding;
  ++col;
  if (col >= cols) {
    col = 0;
    xx = padding + rowEndPadding;
    if (++row === rows - 1) {
      xx += finalRowEndPadding;
    }
    yy += padding + imgHeight;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: This is great! I was missing the `finalRowEndPadding` logic. You helped me to refine the function, thanks!